# iOS - Replace SegmentControl with navigation title programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view controller whose navigation bar has a segment control. Now I want reuse this view controller to display something else with a title instead of a segment control. I tried to set the segment control's hidden propertory to `true` and set `self.navigationController?.title = "foo"`, unfortunately, no title shows :(

How can I replace `UISegmentedControl` with my navigation title programmatically?

Comment: Take a look at the [titleView property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) which you probably have to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [titleView property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) of the `navigationController` to `nil` since the docs state

> If this property value is nil, the navigation item’s title is displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top item. If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title. This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the UISegmentedView in the titleView like this

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
```